# Проблема с парсингом avito.ru

Tags: curl, php, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь парсить сайт avito.ru

```
function getContent($url, $referer){
$cookie='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; uk; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 Some plugins');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$header = substr($data,0, curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$body = substr($data, curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i", $header, $res);
$cookie = '';
foreach ($res[1] as $key => $value) {
$cookie = $value.'='.$res[2][$key].'; ';
};
curl_close($ch);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; uk; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 Some plugins');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$data2 = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $data2;
}

$html = getContent('http://www.avito.ru', 'http://google.com');
echo $html;
```

В первый раз нормально парсит (получает всё содержимое avito.ru), когда обновляешь то ничего не парсится, просто белый экран, нужно ждать некоторое время либо закрывать браузер и снова парсить, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А в чем сакральный смысл двойного подключения с одними и теми же настройками?

Comment: первый раз подключаемся и берём куки, второй раз их отправляем

Comment: по другому не получается, только с одинаковыми настройками

Answer (score 2):

Обновляя страницу, в первой части ты подтверждаешь отсутствие кук, 
а он их уже отдал в прошлый раз и тебя банят.

Надо сохранить себе куки из первой части запроса и подставлять теперь в каждый запрос как во второй части.